# Vuetify TextArea Width issues

Tags: vuetify.js

I have 2 columns, 1 with a textarea. The code below gives me what I want except that my textarea is narrow. I want it to be the full width of the v-card. What am I missing?

See the example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YbgwaN?editors=1010)

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card>
      <v-container fluid>
        <v-layout row>
          <v-flex md7>
            <v-card dark color="green darken-2">
              <textarea full-width rows=30  min-height=500 v-model="message">
                </textarea>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>

          <v-flex md5 >
            <v-card dark color="blue darken-2">
              <pre v-highlightjs="sourcecode"><code class="html">{{message}}
              </code></pre>
            </v-card>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: `<textarea>` is HTML element. You might wanted to use `<v-textarea>`, Vutetify component where `full-width` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props like `full-width` are implelemted by Vuetify components. `<textarea>` is HTML element, therefore it doesn't know about Vuetify 'magic' props.

`<v-textarea>` is what you are looking for.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/textarea

Or you can use old-fasioned inline-style (quite not recommended if you can use the advantage of vuetfiy).

```html
<textarea style="width:100%;"></textarea>
```